# Downloading excel file from .aspx page

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net

The link is a `.aspx` page which asks for a start date and end date. Then after providing the dates and clicking on a button, the `data(text)` gets loaded on that page. I want to somehow be able to automate this process and fetch that data.

In the source code of that page, I found this `javascript` function

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)
```

but there is no call to this function.

My current java code:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", "Excel"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate));
params.add(newBasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION",eventvalidation));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FromDate", startDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ToDate", endDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
```